# How to implement optional authentication in React/Express app?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

I'm building self-hosted bookmarks manager app. I'm using React on frontend and Express on backend. I have already implemented normal authentication system based on JWT. But now I want to make authentication optional. Beacuse it's self-hosted app some users might want to use it only on local network = auth disabled, and other expose it to the Internet = auth enabled.

On backend, I'm using env variable `USE_AUTH=false` to disable authentication and everything works as it should.

On frontend however, I'm rendering some components and routes based on `isAuthenticated` value stored in AuthContext state. It is set to true on successful login/sign up and to false on logout.

**My question** is how can I tell my React frontend that I'm not using auth on backend so it can render all hidden components, don't include token to requests etc.?

The only solution I came up with, is to send request when user opens the app to ask server if it's using authentication. So something like `GET /api/auth/ping` will return `{ useAuth: true }` or `{ useAuth: false }` depending on `USE_AUTH` value.

**But** I don't know if it is as optimal solution. Is there a better option / pattern I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to do this is to specify in your react app, which routes are private and which ones are public, depending on that, components will be rendered.